# Is there a way to have a single for loop return different values for different user inputs?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a single for-loop that uses the variable 'lapTime' to store the current lapTime for hypothetical skiers. The skiers are to complete 5 laps and each lap there is a slow rate of 10%. The method I am writing should allow the user to input their lap number and my for loop should predict the time that the skier will finish their lap.

slowRate Formula:

```
nextLapTime = previous lap time + (previous lap time * slowrate);
```

I tried using "if-else" statements in the for loop to force it to return different values that are dependent on the users lapNumber input, but that only breaks the for-loop (dead code error). 
Currently, the for-loop only returns one value for each time it iterates through the loop -- 11 seconds. I've tried doing: `lapTime = lapTime  + (lapTime * slowRate)`, but that returns 16.(numbers) for whatever weird reason. Even though lapTime should be set equal to firstLapTime which == 10. The code I have provided below returns a value of 15 -- idk why..

The For-Loop:

```
public double getLapTime(double firstLapTime, double slowRate, int lapNumber) 

    double lapTime;
    lapTime = firstLapTime;
    for (lapNumber=1; lapNumber<=5; lapNumber ++) {
        lapTime = lapTime + (firstLapTime * slowRate);
    }
    return lapTime;
    }
```

Here are the test methods that I am trying to debug --

1)

```
public void testShouldHaveSecondLapOf11Seconds() {

    // Act: call our method with proper parameter value for our test
    double actualResult = theCalculator.getLapTime(10, .1, 2);

    // Assert: assert that our expected value is equal to the actual result
    assertEquals(11.0, actualResult, 0.001);
```

2)

```
public void testShouldHaveThirdLapOf12Point1Seconds() {

    // Act: call our method with proper parameter value for our test
    double actualResult = theCalculator.getLapTime(10, .1, 3);

    // Assert: assert that our expected value is equal to the actual result
    assertEquals(12.1, actualResult, 0.001);
}
```

I am expecting to receive the values as shown in the JUnit tests, and somehow 
the logic in my for-loop is not returning the lapTimes that it should. It returns only one number for each iteration of the loop.

PS.. this is one of my first posts, so sorry in advance for any formatting issues. I'll try my best to improve on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the for loop itself. because even though you call getLapTime() method and pass 3 as the `lapNumber`, you still assign the value 1 to it in your for loop. So, instead that your `lapNumber` is equal to 3, it's actually equal to 1.

```
for (lapNumber=1 /* your chaning the value of lapNumber here to 1 */; lapNumber<=5; lapNumber ++) {
    lapTime = lapTime + (firstLapTime * slowRate);
}
```

you can try

```
for (int i = lapNumber; i <= 5; i++) {
    lapTime = lapTime + (firstLapTime * slowRate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two mistakes in your code.

The first one is in the way you made your for loop. I believe you want to compute the next lap's time at each iteration. One iteration will give you the 2nd lap, 2 iterations will yield the 3rd lap time etc. This is not what you are currently doing as you are always computing the 5th lap time.

Then, by looking at the answer expected for the second lap, I think the *slowdown is relative to the last lap performed*, not the first one. Otherwise you wouldn't need a for loop to compute the nth lap time, you would just need to compute the absolute slowdown once, multiply that by the number of laps you want and add it to the first lap's time. The weird reason why it was not working before is because of the faulty for loop iteration problem you have.

I would suggest this for loop:

```
for (int id = 1; i < lapNumber; i++) {
    lapTime = lapTime + (lapTime * slowRate);
}
```